# Removing empty {} from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to remove empty elements in `Text` column:

```
Text
{python, c}
{coding, programming}
{}
{}
```

I have tried using `dropna` but it has not worked.
How can I remove these empty elements?

Comment: Can you please show exactly *how* `dropna` was tried? There are a few ways this can ‘fail’ (give unexpected results) if unaware.

Comment: `df.Text.dropna(subset=['Text'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `astype`

```
df = df[df['Text'].astype(bool)]
```